# Dividing shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, splitting

I am working currently with QGIS. I have loaded the shapefile into my function. Now my problem is: in the shapefile are different with different kinds of points (one for arrow, one for ...) and these are all in one shapefile.

How can I create a separate shapefile for each kind of point so that there are three instead of one then accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To split one shape file into separate shape files (based on one attribute field) you can use Vector > Datamanagement Tools > Split Vector Layer

[image]